# Azure Connection Issue After upgrading plan

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

About a month ago I went from an S1 app service plan to an S2 app service plan so my .NET webapp would have more ram. While the application worked just fine, the "Debugger Snapshot" wouldn't fire sometimes because I was > 80% memory usage.

So I do the update, and everything seemed to be working ok for about a week. Now, seemingly randomly, I'm getting these random SQL errors:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An
> operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked
> sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.) An operation on
> a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient
> buffer space or because a queue was full.

This *seems* like it's a SQL connection issue, but it seems odd to me that after 3 years I would suddenly start getting this error just a week after upgrading my service plan.

However, on my dashboard for my webapp, I get this weird dropout at the same time for memory:

[image]

Nothing has changed on SQL, my load hasn't increased, not sure what to make of this or where to start.

Comment: Please check you code that if you have many connections/requests to Azure SQL database, per my experience, that mostly caused in code level. Please open the connection once the session finished.

Comment: My ORM is EntityFramework 6.4.4. My load isn't any greater than before the app service plan change. Why would a connection problem suddenly occur?